# How to access light DOM info from Javascript in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

Question:

In Web Components specification, when you want to read elements within a `Light-DOM` from the template the `<content select></content>` element can be used. But, how can this information be retrieved from the javascript code of the component?

Example:

```
<wc-timer>
    <wc-timer-title>I want to read this from JS</wc-timer-title>
</wc-timer>
```

Thanks in advance, Javier.

Answer (score 7):

Remember that `this` inside of your prototype methods refers to the element itself. IOW, just like you could do `element.innerHTML` or `element.firstChild` you can write `this.innerHTML` or `this.firstChild`.

Simple mode:

```
domReady: function() {
  console.log(this.textContent);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/bociz/2/edit

This gets more complicated if you are using `<content>` to project nodes through multiple levels of Shadow DOM. In this case, you will need to use `getDistributedNodes` api of the `<content>` node itself.

Before getting into that, I suggest you start with the simple version, and ask a follow up question if you get into trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Use `this`, for accessing lightDOM and
use  `this.shadowRoot` to access shadowDOM

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the template renders out as to the dom, but maybe you can try this:

```
//jQuery
$('wc-timer-title').text();

//Plain
document.getElementsByTagName("wc-timer-title")[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `/deep/`, it is being deprecated but there is no date as to when that will happen.